# Dynamic getters in pinia - Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, pinia

There is code for **Vue 2 with Vuex 3.4**:

```js
getLink: (state, getters) => rel => {
  let link = state.data?.getLinkWithRel(rel);
  let stac = getters[rel];
  let title = STAC.getDisplayTitle([stac, link]);
  if (link) {
    link = Object.assign({}, link);
    link.title = title;
  }
  else if (stac instanceof STAC) {
    return {
      href: stac.getAbsoluteUrl(),
      title,
      rel
    };
  }
  return link;
},
```

This code should be ported to **Vue 3 with pinia**. Did the following:

```js
getLink: (state) => (rel) => {
  let link = state.data?.getLinkWithRel(rel);
  let stac = state[rel];
  let title = STAC.getDisplayTitle([stac, link]);

  if (link) {
    link = { ...link };
    link.title = title;
  }
  else if (stac instanceof STAC) {
    return {
      href: stac.getAbsoluteUrl(),
      title,
      rel
    };
  }

  return link;
},
```

The `stac` variable contains either `null` or `undefined` values.

When using version 1, `stac` contains the data returned by the called `getters[rel]` function.

## How do I write or force pinia to give data?

Additional information:

`rel` - contains a string with one of the getter names (`parent` or `collection`).

getter-parent:

```js
parent: (state) => state.getStacFromLink('parent'),
```

Where `getStacFromLink` is also a getter.

getter-collection:

```js
collection: (state) => state.getStacFromLink('collection'),
```

It looks like the `parent` or `collection` getters that are called do not get the state of the Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution seems a bit over complicated to me.

If both getters `parent` and `collection` just call `getStacFromLink` with hardcoded `rel`, then why not simply

```
let stac = state.getStacFromLink(rel);
```

I haven't found a way to access getters dynamically in `Pinia`.
And I think it's is good so. Consider to overthink your getters and store design.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const { createPinia, defineStore, storeToRefs } = Pinia

const Store = defineStore('test',
{
    state: () => {
      return { data: 
        {
          getLinkWithRel: (rel) => {
             return { href: rel, title: rel }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    getters: {
      parent: (state) => state.getStacFromLink('parent'),
      getStacFromLink: (state) => (rel) => {
        return { stac: rel }
      },      
      getLink: (state, getters) => (rel) => {
        let link = state.data?.getLinkWithRel(rel);
        console.log(link);
        let stac = state.getStacFromLink(rel);
        console.log(stac);             
        return link;
      }
    }
  }
)

const App = {
  setup() {
    const store = Store()
    const refs = storeToRefs(store)
    return {
      store, refs
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
getLink('parent'):  {{ store.getLink('parent') }}<br/>
getLink('collection'):  {{ store.getLink('collection') }}<br/>
refs['parent']: {{ refs['parent'] }}
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi@0.13.11/lib/index.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.30/dist/pinia.iife.js"></script>
```